# Crossfading Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to crossfade and cycle through a  series of 5 images which is a full screen background image.

I am applying the following css class to body.

```
body {
   display: table;
   margin:0px;
   height:100%;
   background-image:url('images/image1.jpg') ;
   background-size: 1500px auto;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important;
}
```

I would like to replace background-image with the next image in sequence i.e. images/image2.jpg, images/image3.jpg, every 8 seconds, with the prior image fading out and the new image fading in, and being able to control the speed of fading.

I was wondering what the best way is to go about doing this. I tried using Jquery Cycle but it didn't fit my needs since this is a full-screen background image.

This link was the most helpful so far.
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg1

Answer (score 0):

```js
images = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png",
"https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--XkYSDzxz--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/hflvykipmc5g22mc3m0m.jpg",
"https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/symbolism/images/4/43/Orange.png/revision/latest?cb=20140818120046",
"https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/joke-battles/images/0/0e/Green.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170111231844"];
// These are just placeholder images, replace the URLs with anything you desire.

bgNum = 0;
setInterval(changeBackground,5000); // Change to the number of milliseconds desired between frame changes
changeBackground();

function changeBackground() {
  c = document.getElementById('bgContainer');
  c.removeChild(c.childNodes[0]);
  bg2 = document.createElement('img');
  bg2.src = images[bgNum];
  bg2.classList.add('bg');
  bg2.style.opacity = '0';
  bg2.onload = setTimeout(changeOpacity,100); // For some reason, updating the opacity does not work immediately after inserting the element
  c.appendChild(bg2);
  bgNum++;
  bgNum %= images.length; // Reset image counter
}

function changeOpacity() {
  c = document.getElementById('bgContainer');
  c.childNodes[0].style.opacity = '0';
  c.childNodes[1].style.opacity = '1';
}
```

```css
#bgContainer img {
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div id='bgContainer'><img><img></div>
test text
```

I could not find any way to replicate this using `background-image`, but I believe this replicates the behavior you are looking forward to. In order to use it, simply change the interval time and image list, as necessary.

I attempted this by having only two images on the page at a time, stacked on top of each other. However, I believe that having all images together at once and alternating opacity values may be cleaner and remove the need for the `setTimeout()` call. Oddly, calling `console.log()` also works instead of setting a delay, but it clutters the console if left running for a long period of time.